# changing image that on my selected child forms picturebox1

Tags: vb.net-2010

how change the image on picturebox1 in childform on vb.net 2010 my app is a mdiform and child, sub on module (for mdiform,property changing or getting codes are include mdiform) is gonna change the image property of the picturebox1 in the child form

Comment: There stored in an array with index `0` to `.Length-1`.

Comment: Is it WinForms, WPF or any other GUI library?

Comment: idk im coming from vb6 i only know form,usercontrol,class and modules

Answer (score 0):

The `Me.MdiChildren` property in the `MdiContainer` contains the references to all the children.

It is a 0-based indexed array. So the first child would be `Dim f = Me.MdiChildren(0)`

To create and add a new form, you can use this type of process in the MDI parent.

```
Private Sub AddNewForm()
    Dim dlg As New ChildForm
    dlg.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    dlg.MdiParent = Me
    dlg.Text = $"Child {Me.MdiChildren.Length}"
    dlg.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: is it comptible with an another dim, is it works? Dim f = Me.MdiChildren(mydim)

Comment: in my app its always 3 form (i made dim that seperates selected ones type) can i change something on my form

Comment: How to use New after =

Comment: Try it out and be specific on what the problem is. I recommend [edit] your question and add the necessary details for what you are trying to do.